# Can someone explain me how "d.maximumDifference" worked in the end? Like can we even call a variable inside a function which is inside a class?

Tags: python, function, class

```
class Difference:
def __init__(self, a):
    self.__elements = a
def computeDifference(self):
    b = min(self.__elements)
    c = max(self.__elements)
    result = abs(b-c)
    self.maximumDifference = result

_ = input()
a = [int(e) for e in input().split(' ')]

d = Difference(a)
d.computeDifference()

print(d.maximumDifference)
```

I am unable to understand how I was able to call maximumdifference, which is a variable inside the computeDifference function, Which is inside the Difference class?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: @ewong, I have put the code in text format

Comment: You set the maximumDifference attribute within the computeDifference() method.  That's why you can access it.  If you didn't call computeDifference(), you'll get an attributeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I was able to call maximumdifference, which is a variable inside the computeDifference function, Which is inside the Difference class?

I think the core of your question comes from a slight misunderstanding: `self.maximumDifference` is a field in the class `Difference`.  This field was created on-the-fly when the `computeDifference` function was called.

As another example:

```
...     def foo(self):
...             self.bar = "hi"
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.bar
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'bar'
>>> a.foo()
>>> a.bar
'hi'
```

Here we can see how the `bar` attribute does not exist until after the `foo` function was run.  If you're familiar with other languages, this may be surprising behavior --- many other languages require that class attributes/fields are fixed/specified in the class or constructor, but Python allows adding new fields on-the-fly.